# Spring-rabbit - ReturnCallback not triggered

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am having problems configuring ReturnCallback when i get a Nack while publishing on an exchange. Here is what I do:

```
CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.setPublisherConfirms(true);
connectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true);
...
RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);
rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback(new MyMessageConfirmCallback());
rabbitTemplate.setReturnCallback(new MyMessageReturnCallback());
```

Then when I publish a message, I send a message to a non-existing exchange

```
notificationProducerJmsTemplate.send("idontexist.exchange",
                                     "idontexist.key",
                                      messageToSend, 
                                      correlationData);
```

The strange thing is that I reach the code defined in `MyMessageConfirmCallback` but not the one in `MyMessageReturnCallback`, even if in the first one the value of `ack` is `false`.

I am using RabbitMQ 3.4.2 and here is my maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Last but not least, here is the error message that I can see in the logs:

```
2015-03-26 16:29:24,094 GMT [pool-21-thread-1] (CachingConnectionFactory.java:281) ERROR connection.CachingConnectionFactory: Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'idontexist.exchange' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
```

Anybody see something wrong ? Any hint on what to check to find out what could prevent the ReturnCallback to be called ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how it works in the Rabbit Client: the `AMQImpl.Close` is initiated from the Broker to close the current `Channel`. That's because `NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'idontexist.exchange' in vhost '/'` is treated as a critical error (`ChannelN#processAsync`):

```
if (method instanceof Channel.Close) {
       asyncShutdown(command);
       return true;
}
```

Hence we don't reach `} else if (method instanceof Basic.Return) {` from there.

The `PublisherCallbackChannelImpl` calls `handleNack` for that case, hence - `ConfirmCallback`.

Comment: Thanks ! I kinda imagined there was something like that involved. The question now is "what can I do to test the ReturnCallback ?"

Comment: Valid `exchange`, invalid `routingKey`. That means "there is no binding for this routingKey"